# what would be the regex pattern for this uri segment?

Tags: regex, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

I have a URI segment

```
/incoming/article1271748.ece5/ALTERNATES/article_main/torm-500.jpg
```

And I need to exclude it using like this

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**/**jpg" access="permitAll"/>
```

So, that filters shouldnt be applied of those urls ending with jpg, png and gif, as it would mess up the url redirection.

So, what could be the pattern which I could try?

Answer (score 1):

The prefereable way to do this is put all static resources into a directory and map it in your conf file like so :

```
<mvc:resources location="/static-assets/" mapping="/static-assets/**"/>
```

Comment: well..it is difficult as the images are handled by CMS..spring is a wrapper around that CMS.